# Emulator showing different output than Xamarin.Forms Previewer

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-emulator

I have `Master` `Layout` of `MasterDetailPage`. Which is showing output as expected in Xamarin.Forms Previewer window. But when I execute it on Android Emulator, output showing little different. How can I solve this issue? My code is

```
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <ContentPage Title="MasterP" >
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#01796F">
        <StackLayout Margin="25,10,25,0" Padding="0,30,0,0">
            <Image  BackgroundColor="Accent" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="Enrich.png"></Image>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout  Margin="20,10,20,0" >
            <Button  Margin="20,5,20,0"   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="Menu 1"></Button>
            <Button  Margin="20,0,20,0"   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="Menu 1"></Button>
            <Button  Margin="20,0,20,0"   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="Menu 1"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Don't trust the previewer. It is a strange contraption trying to run your forms code in some kind of sandbox environment, which isn't behaving exactly as it would run natively, especially when it comes to custom classes and native resources.

Make sure to have your UI optimized on the emulator or some real devices and you are good to go.

Comment: @MarkusMichel - Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Previewer won't necessarily have the same screen dimensions as the phone you are emulating. There will be some differences between the Previewer and an emulator/physical device.

The Aspect property you have set will file the entire view, clipping off other edges. Have a look at [the Aspect Enum documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.aspect?view=xamarin-forms) on the Microsoft Docs. It sounds like the aspect you want is `AspectFit`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.